# Hiding status bar when softkeyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, statusbar, android-fullscreen

I want to hide status bar in my status bar and this is how I do it:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
```

}

The issue is when the soft keyboard becomes visible (typing in an EditText), the status bar comes back.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do on .java, just code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
```

but if you want to hide status bar on xml, just code:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/system-ui/status.html for more information...

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question asks how to prevent the status bar from appearing when the soft keyboard is shown. the FLAG_FULLSCREEN has nothing to do with the fact that the system will always show the status bar when the soft keyboard is displayed.